# Is Duckworth–Lewis applied differently in T20 and ODI

Tags: cricket, duckworth-lewis

I want to know: is there any difference between ODIs and T20 matches in applying the Duckworth–Lewis method?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the method of application of Duckworth-Lewis, between matches.

The only potential difference could be in the tables or equivalent that are used to generate the targets, which should reflect different scoring rates and potentials between the two match types.

However as suggested by http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/459431.html, the 50 over curves are used by the 20 over version.

Comment: On the ICC's website, in the document [The D/L methodology: answers to frequently asked questions](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542b84d41b3c2-The%20D_L%20methodology%20-%20Answers%20to%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.docx), there is a section ("Twenty20 issues") that discusses how the method is applied in T20.